# Retrofit service class not injected in ViewModel using dagger2

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, dagger-2

I am trying to inject retrofit created API service in ViewModel, as following:

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var service: LoginService

    var username : String=""
    var password : String=""

    fun signInClicked(){
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(username).matches()){
            return
        }else if(password.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
       val call = service?.getCurrentWeatherData("35","139","2e65127e909e178d0af311a81f39948c")
        call?.enqueue(object :Callback<Model.WeatherResponse>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model.WeatherResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE","FAILURE")
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Model.WeatherResponse>,
                response: Response<Model.WeatherResponse>
            ) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE","SUCCESS")
            }

        })
    }
}
```

This is my dagger Module class

```
    @Module
class NetworkingModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getRetrofit() : Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getLoginAPIService(retrofit: Retrofit):LoginService {
        return retrofit.create(LoginService::class.java)
    }
}
```

This is my Dagger component

```
 @Singleton
@Component(modules = [NetworkingModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    
}
```

I am getting error "lateinit property service has not been initialised" when try to access service variable in LoginViewModel

Comment: This is field injection you need call inject with component .. its better if you add this field to constructor the  it will be automatically injected .

Comment: as @ADM said, for view models you should use constructor injection. its better use field injection only in framework classes like activity, fragments and ...

Comment: Singleton `ViewModel`? Not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @ADM I had tried to put it in constructor then I was getting error :"    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.healthwithveda.ui.login.LoginViewModel
"

Comment: @BartekLipinski Thanks, I was trying to fix this issue by trying this. I have removed SingleTone annotation from ViewModel

Comment: Just so you understand this: you should let the arch components library maintain `ViewModel` instances. By using `@Singleton` annotation you're making the instance retained in the dependency graph.

Answer (score 0):

1. first define a method that takes `ViewModel` as an argument

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = [NetworkingModule::class]) 
    interface ApplicationComponent {
    public void injectInViewModel(ViewModel viewModel); }
```

2. `Make` you project and build the component in `viewmodel` inside `init` block.

```
    init{
               mComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create().injectInViewModel(this);
           }
```